# Android Galaxy S3 icon not appearing with phonegap build

Tags: android, cordova, icons, config, galaxy

I have been working on this issue for several days now.  I know there are various suggestions on the solution, but dare I say, I've tried them all.  Bottomline, there is no icon appearing on my Galaxy S3 when I download my app after a PhoneGap Build. I built the app in Dreamweaver, zip the file, upload it to PG, and then use my QR reader to download the build.  The app works, the icon doesn't appear.  I've tried just getting the default android icon to appear with no success.  I've tried using the https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start demo and again, it works with no icon. Here is what I have in the config.xml file:

```
<icon src="icon.png" />
<icon src="icon_96.png" width="96" height="96" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi"/>
<icon src="icon_72.png" width="72" height="72" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi"/>
<icon src="icon_48.png" width="48" height="48" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi"/>
<icon src="icon_36.png" width="36" height="36" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi"/>
```

I have even tried copying the files into Eclipse and changing the file path a little to reflect the icon Eclipse builds for you, with no success. I really am at a loss here and feel like I have exhausted the main online resources for the answer. I also feel like the answer is right in front of me and relatively simple (it usually is, right?)  Ha, please, any help is much appreciated.  Best wishes,

David

Answer (score 0):

My test device is an ASUS tablet, and I've found that if I specify android-specific icons at all, then I get the default phonegap icon. But if I specify a platform-agnostic icon, and IOS icons, then my application icon is used for android (presumably the default one in the root folder.)

No idea what the issue is - there wouldn't appear to be anything wrong with the format of the files, since it shows the default just fine. And I've tried every permutation of file location and width/height vs. density in the config.xml file.